# Javascript D3 - put results into a DIV

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've found a script that produces a map of the UK using Javascript D3.  I have no idea how this library works, but the code is fine.  What I want to do is create a `<div>` in the body:

```
<body>
  <div id = "put_map_here"></div>
</body>
```

Run the map script at the end of the page:

```
var width = 960,   
    height = 1160; 

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * 5)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("data/uk-postcode-area.json", function(error, uk) {
  svg.selectAll(".postcode_area")
      .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects["uk-postcode-area"]).features)
     .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "postcode_area")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
             return "#AAA";
           })                        
      .append("svg:title")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects["uk-postcode-area"], function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "mesh")
      .attr("d", path);      

});
```

And then populate the `<div>` via javascript:

```
document.getElementById("put_map_here").innerHTML = ???
```

However I'm struggling to get the map in the `<div>` using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, just change

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

To

```
var svg = d3.select("#put_map_here").append("svg")
```